# monday api creates item but doesnt fill the other fields

Tags: javascript, monday.com

so im using the monday api in my code and im trying to add new items to a board, well the item gets added but the other fields are empty

```
const mondaySdk = require("monday-sdk-js");
const mondayApiKey = require("./apiKeys");
const monday = mondaySdk();
monday.setToken(mondayApiKey);

 const userData = {
    Email: "lol@lol.com",
    level: {label: "Pro"},
  
  };

  
  const encodedUserData = JSON.stringify(userData).replace(/"/g, "\\\"");

  
  const mutation = `
  mutation {
    create_item (
      board_id: 12345,
      item_name: "New Item",
      column_values: "${encodedUserData}") {
      id
    }
  }
`;
  
  monday
      .api(mutation)
      .then((response) => res.send({response, encodedUserData}))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error); 
        res.send(error);
      });
```

[image]